# Lazy loading and expandableRowGroups in a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm struggelling with PrimeFaces DataTable and lazy loading. This is my table:

```
<p:dataTable var="entry"
            value="#{app.table}" scrollable="true"
            scrollHeight="400" virtual="true" lazy="true" virtualScroll="true"
            rows="40" scrollRows="20"
            sortBy="#{entry.group}" sortOrder="ascending"
            expandableRowGroups="true"
            resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
    <p:headerRow>
        <p:column colspan="2">
             <h:outputText value="#{entry.group}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:headerRow>
    <p:column headerText="Group">
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.group}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Value">
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.value}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Initially everything looks fine. Grouping and entries are correct. But after scrolling (and loading next rows) all groups are lost. Even  if you scroll back to the top.

Does PrimeFaces support lazy loading and grouping in the same table? Is there something I need to consider when using groups with LazyDataModel? Are there examples of tables with expandableRowGroups and lazy loading?

Setting *rows=#{app.table.size()}* solves the problem (but also disables lazy loading). This is not an option for > 5k rows.

TIA!

Comment: PrimeFaces 1.0 does not support this... not sure about your version. And am I correct that it works without liveresize or other options

Comment: I'm using PrimeFaces 8.0 an it does not work without liveresize or other options.  I've tried some combinations of options, but lazy and expandableRowGroups seem to be mutally exclusive.